# Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed. (Cloud function)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error only when the function is called multiple times in short intervals of time, occasionally when it is called a single time.

From the other responses, it suggest to return null as a Promise for the Firebase cloud functions. This function is called inside a Firebase cloud function every time a new document is created. Any thought?

```
function createMilestone(path : String){

    var reg = "[^£]*£[^£]*";
    const uid = path.match(reg);
    if (uid){

    let ref = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("0")
    let ref1 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("1")
    let ref2 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("2")
    let ref3 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("3")
    let ref4 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("4")
    let ref5 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("5")
    let ref6 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("6")
    let ref7 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("7")
    let ref8 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("8")
    let ref9 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(path).collection("0").doc("9")

       batch.set(ref ,arrayMilestones[0]);
       batch.set(ref1, arrayMilestones[1]);
       batch.set(ref2, arrayMilestones[2]);
       batch.set(ref3, arrayMilestones[3]);
       batch.set(ref4, arrayMilestones[4]);
       batch.set(ref5, arrayMilestones[5]);
       batch.set(ref6, arrayMilestones[6]);
       batch.set(ref7, arrayMilestones[7]);
       batch.set(ref8, arrayMilestones[8]);
       batch.set(ref9, arrayMilestones[9]);


       batch.commit().then(function () {
        console.log("imported milestones")
        return null

      });
    }
```

Comment: A Cloud Function callback must return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete in that function.  Just calling `then` on a promise is not sufficient. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: Can you include the error trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the Promises chain, as follows

```
function createMilestone(path : String){

       //.....

       return batch.commit().then(function () {
        console.log("imported milestones")
        return null;
      });

    }
```

If you don't need the `console.log()` just do

```
function createMilestone(path : String){

       //.....

       return batch.commit();

    }
```

---

If you still encounter problems, please add to your code the entire Cloud Function code, not just a snippet.